# Laravel Excel get importing cell access with URL

Tags: excel, laravel, cell, laravel-excel

I'm working with [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/) and [Laravel Excel 3.1](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) on importing the sheet and there is no way to access to the current Cell object and its Hyperlink/URL there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the solution! Use Laravel Excel Import-to-model with `OnEachRow` interface: [Handling persistence on your own](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#handling-persistence-on-your-own) and code little bit more

```
<?php
//call your import script
config(['excel.imports.read_only' => false]); // to get access to all of the cells content
\Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::import(new \App\Imports\Sheet1, $xlsFile);
```

Laravel Excel Import class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Imports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Cell;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;

class Sheet1 implements OnEachRow
{
    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        foreach ($row->getDelegate()->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
            $cellObj = new Cell($cell); //Laravel Facade Cell Object
            $cellPHPOffice = $cellObj->getDelegate(); // PHP SpreadsheetCell object
            if ($cellPHPOffice->hasHyperlink()) {
                $url = $cellPHPOffice->getHyperlink()->getUrl(); // Cell URL: works ONLY with excel.imports.read_only => false
            }
        }
    }
}
```